# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing GDAL for Python3 on AWS EC2

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, amazon-ec2, gdal, rhel

I'm trying to install GDAL to use with Python 3 on an AWS EC2 Amazon2 machine (RHEL7).
Following the instructions on this page: [Install GDAL on Python 2.7 on a Amazon Linux virtual server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940071/install-gdal-on-python-2-7-on-a-amazon-linux-virtual-server) I managed to get it working for python 2.7 ("import gdal from osgeo" works).

However, I need it to work for python3 installed on my machine. I tried to adjust the instructions accordingly, and got to this set of commands:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum -y install make automake gcc gcc-c++ libcurl-devel proj-devel geos-devel gdal-devel gdal-python python3-devel 
sudo yum -y update
cd /tmp
curl -L http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.4.0/gdal-2.4.0.tar.gz | tar zxf -
cd gdal-2.4.0/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-python
sudo make -j4
sudo make install
python3 -m pip install numpy --user
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
sudo python3 -m easy_install GDAL -d /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages --include-dirs=/usr/include/gdal
```

when I run the last command, the installation tries to run but fails with:

```
"error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1".
```

There are many errors before that, such as:

```
 /usr/local/include/cpl_vsi_error.h:58:24: error: ‘CPL_FORMAT_STRING’ has not been declared
CPL_FORMAT_STRING(const char *fmt), ... )
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3173:0:
```

From what I gather, the gcc can't find the GDAL headers, but it is specified in the command and I also did the including commands above:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
```

Any ideas will be helpful!

Comment: any solution you found?

Comment: Not sure... I think I used another type of linux machine from AQS